# How does passing an object with the keyword 'this' work?

Tags: java, this

I wrote a little java game for a school assignment where we had to click on moving ellipses to gain points.
Here are the two classes I made:

The disk class

```
package hw22;
import processing.core.PApplet
public class Disk{
static PApplet cv;

Disk(PApplet canvas){
cv = canvas;} // end of disk constructor
}// End of disk class
```

The myGame class

```
package hw22;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class myGame extends PApplet {
//Some code
Disk d = new Disk(this);. //here I am passing it myGame
 // Do some stuff
}// End of myGame class
```

So my question is this:

If I'm passing the disk class' constructor a myGame object when it's expecting a PApplet object then why is my game working? Shouldn't eclipse be complaining about me passing the wrong type of object?

Comment: this is your class `myGame` so in this line `Disk d = new Disk(this);` you're passing `myGame` to Disk class contructor

Comment: `myGame` extends `PApplet`. There is no error here.

Comment: Relevant tutorial in [Java Nuts and Bolts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `myGame` extends `PApplet`, it means that any object of class `myGame` is *also* a `PApplet`, possibly  with some extra features that regular `PApplet` objects don't have.  But whenever your code requires a `PApplet` reference, a `myGame` reference will do just fine, because a `myGame` *is* a `PApplet`.  And because you're using `this` inside the `myGame` class, `this` is in fact a reference to a `myGame`.